# Search folder with unread mail and draft replies

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've created a search folder using the query builder that only shows unread mail, or flagged mail. Unfortunately, this means as I reply to an email (with the inline reply option turned on), it disappears from the search folder.

Is there a field I can use in the query builder to keep these "read" but "being replied to" emails in the search folder? Or am I just going to have to turn off the inline reply feature?